# My question is about android activity intent

Tags: java, android, kotlin

when we move to the next activity in android through intent then the next activity is shown on the screen and the previous activity hide. when we press the back button it goes to the previous activity back. My question is which function called when we use intent from ist activity to another.Is onPause() ,onStop() or any other plz answer

Comment: where the previous activity goes??

Comment: `onStop()` is called when we call the application and when switching its likely `onPause()`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

Comment: I think you are referring to activity lifecycle. You can get a better idea from the following link. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for how the [Activity Manager and backstack work](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack).

[image: activity manager and backstack]

Answer (score 0):

In 1st Activity OnPause() will be called when we call intent

In 2nd Activity  OnCreate() -> OnStart() -> OnResume() will get called

***Note***
According to the documentation, **SECOND Activity.onResume()** is supposed to be called before **FIRST Activity.onStop()**

```
For Better Understanding please read Android lifecycle of Activity from developer/medium then go to Intent type
```

**Must Do**

```
For practice purpose create two activity and just override all method of
activity life cycle with log n then call intent n check log.
```